# How to create a lua script for fluentbit throttle by specific key

Tags: lua, fluentd, fluent-bit, fluent-bit-rewrite-tag

I would like to throttle logs per kubernetes service - in other other words apply throttle filter for specific tags or keys.
Fluentd had a group_key attribute that enables throttling at a service level but Fluent-bit does not.

This is the configuration of the throttle filter

```
[FILTER]
        Name     throttle
        Match    kube.*
        Rate     1000
        Window   300
        Interval 1s
```

The `Match` key throttles on the whole for all records that matches the tag `kube.*`. I want to be able to include the namespace name in here and create like number of throttle filters to throttle based on a specific namespaces.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration adds throttling per namespace:

```lua
[FILTER]
    Name          throttle
    Match         kubernetes.*_my-namespace1_*
    Alias         my-namespace1
    Rate     1000
    Window   300
    Interval 1s

[FILTER]
    Name          throttle
    Match         kubernetes.*_my-namespace2_*
    Alias         my-namespace2
    Rate     1000
    Window   300
    Interval 1s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lua script in fluent-bit to do rate limiting based on kubernetes service.

Example script - https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/scripts/rate_limit.lua